# Multiply by the number of command output

Tags: linux, bash

Good afternoon there was a need to translate seconds to milliseconds. Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(ffprobe -i c848a39afc54e04cc64ddd955686654b9b1c6f31 -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0");
b=1000;
result=$(($a*$b));
echo $result
```

output

```
./sectomilisec: line 4: 23.760000*1000: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".760000*1000")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bash` doesn't support float operation. You can use `bc` for this:

```
result=$(echo "$a*$b" | bc)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution will only work with integers. To get a working solution with rational numbers, I suggest piping the output into [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html):

```
"$a*$b" | bc
```

Example:

```
$ echo "9 * .3" | bc
# 2.7
```

This solution will be valid for non-integers.

[Also see here for plenty of other possible options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40786/how-to-do-integer-float-calculations-in-bash-or-other-languages-frameworks)